# Access properties of JSON object directly in client-side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I've been tasked with converting a one-page ASP.NET MVC 3 web app to ASP.NET 3.5 Web Forms app due to some incompability with Sharepoint. I'm unable to the access the property of an object in json result of the web forms app. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Also, is it better to use a WCF service or a regular web service when using web forms for returning json data? Can anyone give me some examples? Is it better to use in-built Javascript serializer or JSON.net library? Here's my code -

MVC method -

```
public ActionResult LoadPerson()
{
   var p = new Person;
   p.Name = "Bob";    
   return Json(new { value = p}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //what is the equivalent of this in webforms so I can access the properties directly?
}
```

MVC javascript file -

```
var person;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/LoadPerson',           
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                person = result.value;
            }
        });
alert(person.Name); //works fine.
```

Web Forms code-behind -

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
    public static string LoadPerson()
    {
        var p = new Person();
        p.Name = "Bob";                
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(p);
    }
```

Web Forms javascript -

```
var person;
     $.ajax({
            url: 'Default.aspx/LoadPerson',
            type: 'POST',  
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                person = result.d;
            }
        });

alert(person.Name); //undefined. Why?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to manually JSON serializing the response from your page method. After running `JSON.parse()` on the response from your service, jQuery is left with a JSON string instead of an object with properties like `.Name`.

[ASP.NET automatically handles that step](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/) (using JavaScriptSerializer internally itself, no less). If you just return the object and let ASP.NET handle the translation, it should work as you expect:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Person LoadPerson()
{
    var p = new Person();
    p.Name = "Bob";                

    return p;
}
```

See this post for a more detailed explanation: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

---

While you're changing the code, I recommend avoiding the `async: false` approach. Since JavaScript runs in single, shared thread, and shares that thread with UI rendering in most browsers, any synchronous code introduces a whole host of performance issues. That may even lead to your script presenting an unresponsive script dialog, giving your users the option to cancel its execution.

Comment: That was it!! Thanks so much. If I remove `asynx:false`, isn't there a chance that the Person object might be null. I'm a huge fan of your site by the way : )

Comment: I've also read your post somewhere that you recommend going the WCF route instead of Web services. How do I go about that? Thanks!

Comment: @user349308: What you're doing now is a good approach if all you need is a JSON endpoint for AJAX calls. It's hard to justify WCF's complexity when you don't need any of its advanced features or flexibility.

Comment: In the link above, the article has code snippet to get some data from server-side to client-side (GetDave method). How do I send a Person object from client-side to server-side? Can I do `var p = new Person;` fill it up with properties and send it over? Will it automatically match client-side Person with the server-side Person? Do you have an example? Thanks so much!

Comment: I just tried the above but firebug says "Person is not defined". The parameter name matches with my server-side code. Here's my code - `var p= new Person();
            p.Name= "test";

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Default.aspx/SavePerson',
                data: { person: p },
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json;',
                dataType: 'json'
            });`

Comment: Found the answer on your site! I had to use `var p = {}` and `data: JSON.stringify({ 'person': p })`. Thanks again.